# click on link using getelementsbytagname

Tags: javascript, excel, onclick, getelementsbytagname, vba

Source Code:

```
<TD CLASS="tbl2" ALIGN="left"><A HREF="javascript: ;"onClick="LCMenu(event,1)">
Principal Payment (25)</A></TD>
<TD CLASS="tbl2" ALIGN="center">02/28/2014</TD>
<TD CLASS="tbl2" ALIGN="center">03/25/2014</TD>
<TD CLASS="tbl2" ALIGN="right">1.458567</TD>
<TD CLASS="tbl2" ALIGN="center">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD CLASS="tbl2" ALIGN="center">02/28/2014</TD>
```

Using the above source code I am trying to click on a link using:

```
Doc.getElementsByTagName("A")(8).Click
```

This method works in submitting the page that I want however it only works sometimes.  Other times it creates an error on the page because the proper URL isn't complete.

The source code that the link I am trying to access is really complex and no one has been able to help.  Let me know if you would like to see the full source page.

Thanks.

Comment: `Doc.getElementsByTagName("A")(8).onclick()`

Comment: @adeneo When using this method vba gives me the Compile Error: "Expected: ="

Answer (score 0):

Will this link always be the 9th (8) link on the page?
You could give that particular anchor an ID and use getElementById to refer to it. That way you are sure that you refer to the correct one.

i.e.

```
<TD CLASS="tbl2" ALIGN="left"><A id="myId" HREF="javascript: ;"onClick="LCMenu(event,1)">
Principal Payment (25)</A></TD>
```

and

```
getElementById("myId").Click()
```

Comment: In order to do that would I need to edit the actual HTML on the website?  If so, that is not possible because I did not create the website, it's one that I use at my job.  When using what I currently have does that basically emulate clicking on the link that I specify with the number 8?  It is strange because it acts as if I am only clicking a part of the link and leaves the URL incomplete.

Comment: getElementsByTagName will return an array with references to all A tags on the page. I don't know what the (8) is supposed to do. I think it should read [8] to select the 9th element from the array. passing (8) assumes a function and getElementsByTagName will not return a function. If you can't edit the page on the server however, I don't know how you expect to change it.